# Open new terminal with bash script and use it

Tags: bash, shell, gnome-terminal

I would like to run a python script multiple times in a new terminal each time so I am making a bash script to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

alias bot_1="cd ../Folder1"
alias bot_2="cd ../Folder2"

gnome-terminal
bot_1
python3 bot_one.py

gnome-terminal
bot_2
python3 bot_two.py
```

I would like to run a python script multiple times in a new terminal each time so I am making a bash script to do this.

With my script I have a new terminal which opens but the following commands are executed in the old and not the new

Comment: `gnome-terminal` opens a new terminal with its *own* shell; the execution of the current shell does not transfer to the new terminal window. (Also, alias expansion is not enabled by default in a non-interactive shell.)

Answer (score 2):

`gnome-terminal` has the ability to execute a command other than the default interactive shell.

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory ../Folder1 -- python3 bot_one.py
gnome-terminal --working-directory ../Folder2 -- python3 bot_two.py
```